# Loop function in Matlab Programming

Tags: matlab

I am trying to make a loop as below description in Matlab programming.
It likes two trees exploration.

**Problem1:**

I create a function with two input variables and output with four vars.

From originCoord(x,y,z) it creates two new coordinates R(x,y,z), L(x,y,z); (R means Right, L: left)

next R(x,y,z) -> new R1(x1,y1,z1) & L1(x1,y1,z1) 
and  L(x,y,z) -> new L2(x2,y2,z2) & R2(x2,y2,z2)

then to be continued
.....

loop will stop when one of the newCcoordinates() == targetCoordinates(xtarget, ytarget).

```
%from initial 3D point (x y z) using treeExploreation fuction to create two 
%new3D points with coordinates (x1,y1,z1) and (x2,y2,z2)
%then from these new point, using this function two create new four 3D_Points...
%x y z are scala
rightPoint = [x1,y1,z1];
leftPoint = [x2,y2,z2];
targetPoint = [xtarget, ytarget, ztarget]; 

%store twop 3D points into coordExplore
coordExplore = [rightPoint,leftPoint];

temp = [];
flag = 0;
while (~flag)

    for i=1:length(coordExplore)
        [newrightPoint,newleftPoint]=treeExploration(coordExplore(i)); %help me at here !!!!
        %this function with input (x,y,z) output two new coordinates i.e.
        % newrightPoint(x3,y3,z3) and newleftPoint(x4,y4,z4)  

    if (newrightPoint==targetPoint) || (newleftPoint==targetPoint)
        %this condition is to compare the output coordinates whether the same as 
        %the targetPoint
        flag=1;
        break;
    else
        temp =[newrightPoint,newleftPoint];
    end    
    end

    coordExplore = temp;
    temp = [];
end
```

I got stuck when the output always greater than input. I cannot use all the output for the next loop.
Please help me to comment on how to make a loop for this case. Thanks.

**Updated problems**:

*I wish coordExplore(1) = rightPoint (x1 y1 z1)

and coordExplore(2) = leftPoint (x2 y2 z2)

BUT with index i=1, coordExplore(1) = x1; i=2 -> coordExplore(2) = y1;

I use the loop with coordExplore(i) in order to work from point-to-point within each point has its own coordinates(x y z). How can I do that?*

**Problem2:**
when one of the newCcoordinates() == targetCoordinates(xtarget, ytarget), how can I know which varibales in which direction from origin loop to last loop generating the result? (like which brands of the tree achieving the target).
In C++, I can use stack to save but in Matlab I do not know how can I save the variable for each loop.

Comment: Sounds like a tree traversal. You can implement that with a recursive function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem 1: 
If I have understood what you want to achieve correctly, something like this should do the job.

```
reached_target = False;
coord = [x, y];

while ~reached_target
    number_of_nodes = size(coord, 1)
    new_coord = zeros(2*number_of_nodes)
    for ii = 1:number_of_nodes
        new_coord(ii*2-1, :) = doRightRunning(coord(ii, 1);
        new_coord(ii*2, :) = doLeftRunning(coord(ii, 2);
    end
    target_ind = new_coord(:, 1) == x_target && new_coord(:, 2) == y_target;
    if any(target_ind)
        reached_target = True;
        disp(find(target_ind));
    end
end
```

However, the code you've shown doesn't match your explanations, so it's not clear if the next layer of the tree is 2 times or 4 times the size of the previous layer.

The code here basically calculates all the left and right runs for the current coordinates until the target is reached.
I haven't tested it yet, so look for bugs.

Problem 2: 
It is not necessary to save the trail for knowing the turns it has made to reach the target. When a matching coordinate is found, its place in the list of coordinates reveal its trail. All you need to do is convert its index to binary and interpret 0 as right turn and 1 as left turn (since in the code, the right turn is placed on top, and the left turn on the bottom).

Example: Let's say we are in the 3rd layer of the tree with 8 coordinates and let's say the 6th coordinate matches the target. So starting from index 0, we have found a match at index which is 101 in binary format. It reveals that the turns to reach this coordinate are Left-Right-Left.

Comment: Hi @Ali, thanks for your comment. I edited my code to better understanding. With i=1 in the loop, disp(coordExplore(i)) -> x1. It does not display (x1, y1, z1) as I mentioned in the question that I need to get the value of the rightPoint with coordinate (x1, y1, z1).
How can I do with i=1 in the loop, coordExplore has value of 1st point of rightPoint (x1 y1 z1) then i=2, coordExplore has 2nd value of leftPoint (x2 y2 z2)?

Comment: @LAMNGOCTAM `coordExplore` has three component for each coordinate all lined up after each other, so if you want to access the three components of the `i`th node, this would work: `treeExploration(coordExplore(3*i-2), coordExplore(3*i-1), coordExplore(3*i))`